# проблема с использованием Json в методе friends.get

Tags: json, vkontakte-api

Попробовал написать простой метод, выдающий список `id` друзей пользователя. Выдаётся ошибка в использовании JSON, которую я не могу исправить.

```
static List < int > getFriends(string user_id) {
    string sqw = "";
    string sURL;

    //StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"D:\" + user_id + ".txt", false, Encoding.UTF8);

    int offset = 0;
    //int cur_num = 0;

    List < int > result = new List < int > ();

    int threshold = 1;
    int k = 0;
    while (k < threshold) {

        sURL = @"https://api.vk.com/method/friends.get?user_id=" + user_id + "&fields=sex&offset=" + offset;

        WebRequest wrGETURL;
        wrGETURL = WebRequest.Create(sURL);
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(sURL);
        request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.94 Safari/537.36";
        Stream objStream;
        objStream = request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader objReader = new StreamReader(objStream);
        sqw = objReader.ReadToEnd();

        string json = sqw;
        JObject o;
        o = JObject.Parse(json);

        int count = int.Parse(o["response"]["count"].ToString());
        if (k == 0) threshold = (count - 1) / 1000 + 1;

        //Console.WriteLine(int.Parse(o["response"]["count"].ToString()));
        //Console.WriteLine(o["response"]["users"].Count());

        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            try {
                //sw.WriteLine(o["response"]["users"][i]["uid"]);
                result.Add(int.Parse(o["response"]["users"][i]["uid"].ToString()));
            } catch (Exception ex) {

            }
        }

        //if (count < 1000) break;
        offset += 1000;
        Console.WriteLine("Finished " + count + ", new offset = " + offset);
        k++;
    }
    //sw.Close();
    //Console.WriteLine("Finished " + user_id);
    return result;
}
```

Подскажите, как решить данную проблему? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте использовать последнюю версию VK Api. Это v=5.40

И парсер должен выглядеть так:

```
int.Parse(o["response"]["items"][i]["id"].ToString()
```